# illegal forward reference in android studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It's an old Eclipse project now being migrated to Android studio. I'm getting one `error: illegal forward reference` error in one particular class. It actually not showing any red error indicator line at the error line suggested by Android Studio IDE. The weird thing is I tried to comment out the method in which is showing illegal forward reference error but even after commenting the Android studio points me to the same line number where it was showed as error previously.

I don't know whether it is Java compiler error or Android Studio IDE error.

**app/build.gradle**:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.karogevideos"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'biz.source_code:base64coder:2010-12-19'
    implementation files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation files('libs/bugsense-trace-3.0.6.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/jid3lib-0.5.1.jar')
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'
    implementation group: 'com.nineoldandroids', name: 'library', version: '2.4.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-net', name: 'commons-net', version: '3.5'
  }
```

**project/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any more details in comments, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try posting your code where error occur !

Answer (score 0):

Put this `jid3lib-0.5.1.jar` jar file in your lib folder. Gradle doesn't find this file in your lib folder Location.

Comment: I'm not even implementing that library jar file, see I commented it out.

Comment: Sorry for that. It's my mistake.